# How to link web pages together

Tags: php, html, css, visual-studio-code

In the code below, I am trying to click on upload and go to upload.php. When you click on the button the browser shows up with Error 404 not found. I have attached a screenshot of where the page is located: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4aDv.png)
Any help would be very appreciated. Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            <div class="top-right links">
                @auth
                    <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                    @endif
                @endauth
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Book Website!
            </div>

            <div class="links">
          # HERE >>
                <a href=upload.php>Upload</a>
                <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Edit</a>
                <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Publish</a>
                <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Search for a Book</a>
                <a href="https://laracasts.com">Book Categories</a>

{{--                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>--}}
{{--                    <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>--}}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to be using blade templating engine, that means you are using laravel. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I am using laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the file `upload.php` located relative to the file you are editing? Ensure you are writing the path accordingly. Also, be sure to have quotes around the file name. Examples: `<a href="./upload.php">Upload</a>` if `upload.php` is in the same folder as the current file, or `<a href="./myfolder/upload.php">Upload</a>` if it is in another folder that is in the current directory or `<a href="../myfolder/upload.php">Upload</a>` if it is in a folder in the previous directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel follow these steps ( skip if you've done them )

1. go to the root of the project and type `php artisan serve`
2. As per laravel's documentation go to your routes folder and make a new file or use an existing one to add your route :

```
Route::get('/upload', function () {
  return view('upload'); 
});
```

3. Rename the upload.php file to upload.twig.php

And keep in mind any views that you add have to be in the resources/views folder

Comment: I am using laravel however I don't have a routes.php, should I create one? Thank you for the response

Comment: I would suggest taking a quick look at the : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#basic-routing. It's explained very well, just follow the instructions in the beginning. Hope it helps, let me know if you are having issues. I've edited my answer as well